# Bing Web Search shows results only for my domain

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, bing-api, bing-search

Using Bing Web Search API, I need to filter results only for my domain, example query:

```
https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/search?q=site:mysite.com+myquery
```

But in results I received not only mysite.com results but also from sites like wikipedia and others.
How I can search result only for my domain?
Bing Custom Search not work for me because I have more than 10k transactions

Comment: The site: element you are using does work correctly, so I wonder if there is a syntax error in the actual query you are executing.  Can you provide an actual query URL that fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your website is probably not known or indexed by Bing. Since you use Bing Search API, not a custom indexing service or search across a sitemap.
The actual Bing website will need to be able to find your site. 
Since it doesn't, this triggers the default behavior of returning as relevant as possible results.

This behavior is valid for urls such as the following:

> https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/search?q=microsoft+site:notAnIndexedWebsite.com

Formatting wise, there is multiple options, as seen [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff795613.aspx).
None of it is a problem in this case.

Comment: Thanks now I recive good query results. maybe it was indexed ((

Answer (score 0):

You can try Bing custom search if it helps (at https://www.customsearch.ai/), especially as it is now in GA. It also provides option to crawl your pages in Bing index through webmaster, if they are not crawled already. This should make sure that you get results only from your website.